# Difference between table row values in the same

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Readings` ( `ID` TEXT, `Reading` TEXT, `Date` TEXT )
```

Every Date I have real Readings from different sensors identified by IDs. Is it possible to get a result table with differences between Readings from sensors with the same ID but for different Dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a [proper date format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), you can look up the corresponding previous value with a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
SELECT ID,
       Date,
       Reading - (SELECT Reading
                  FROM Readings AS R2
                  WHERE R2.ID   = Readings.ID
                    AND R2.Date < Readings.Date
                  ORDER BY Date DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                 ) AS Difference
FROM Readings;
```

Comment: Hi, CL! Thanks for prompt advise! I am using Date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format presented as Text. Your solution returned 367 rows, I expected to have 39 rows.

Comment: This query returns one row for every row in the table. If that is not what you want, edit the question to clarify it, i.e., show sample data and the expected result.